# locate where the program is hung

Tags: gdb

When I use gdb to attach a hung process, and get below info.
How could I know where is the key point?
And what it is at the address '0x000000000041f828'?

Thanks in advance,

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00002b2a5b2c379a in sigsuspend () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000041e9fe in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000041fd9b in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000041f7d9 in ?? ()
#4  0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#7  0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#8  0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#10 0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#11 0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#12 0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#13 0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#14 0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#15 0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000041f828 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000403bc5 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000405f93 in ?? ()
#19 0x00002b2a5b2b0994 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#20 0x0000000000403729 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I use gdb to attach a hung process, and get below info.

There are two likely causes for the output you got:

1. You have attached the process without specifying the executable which is running, or
2. Your binary is fully stripped.

For case 1, don't do this:

```
gdb
(gdb) attach 1234
```

Do this instead:

```
gdb -p 1234
```

or this:

```
gdb /path/to/binary 1234
```

or this:

```
gdb /path/to/binary
(gdb) attach 1234
```

For case 2, don't fully strip the binary, as it makes debugging impossible. If you didn't do it as a separate build step, look for "stray" `-s` or `-Wl,-s` on the link line, and remove it.